# CORS blocked - Spring Boot and React

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot

I have my Spring Boot REST API.  Link: "http://localhost:8080/api/components/component/list"

For the frontend, I am using React, above is the link that I want the React Admin app to consume.

Here is my Spring Boot's CORS Code, it is in a separate class called CorsConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry myCorsRegistry){
             myCorsRegistry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000")  //frontend's link
            .allowedHeaders("*")
            .allowedMethods("*")
            .allowCredentials(true)
            .maxAge(4800);
     }

}
```

I also tried this, but it still does not work:

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig{

   @Bean
   public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
       return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
           @Override
           public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/api/**")
                    .allowedOrigins("http://domain2.com")
                    .allowedMethods("PUT", "DELETE")
                    .allowedHeaders("header1", "header2", "header3")
                    .exposedHeaders("header1", "header2")
                    .allowCredentials(false).maxAge(3600);
           }
       };
    }
}
```

For my controller class I have the following:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping("/api/components/component")
@RestController
public class Component{
     @Autowired
     //code...
}
```

Here is my React Code:

```
const parentURL = 
restProvider(`http://localhost:8080/api/components/component`);

function App() {
    return(
       <Admin dataProvider={parentURL}>
          <Resource name="list" list={ListGuesser} />
        </Admin>
    );
 }
```

Here is the error I am getting in my Chrome console:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/api/components/component/DashBoard? 
filter=%7B%7D&range=%5B0%2C9%5D&sort=%5B%22id%22%2C%22ASC%22%5D' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' 
has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response 
serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

**My Question:**
How to fix the above error ?

Comment: try with `allowedOrigins("*")`, if it works let me know

Comment: In Controller when you are adding @CrossOrigin annotation, try specifying the origin there. It should work. `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")`

Comment: sai manoj: Are you running the sprint boot application in the in-build tomcat sever or deploying the jar or war file in the tomcat or any other server?

Answer (score 2):

try adding @CrossOrigin(origins ="http://localhost:3000") on top of your controller. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Please add below file in your project in package where Main spring boot class is present. This worked for me for all CORS issues in Spring boot , React eco system.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class CorsWebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
        registry.addMapping("/*.html");
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/api/v2/api-docs", "/v2/api-docs");
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/api/swagger-resources/configuration/ui",
                "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui");
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/api/swagger-resources/configuration/security",
                "/swagger-resources/configuration/security");
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/api/swagger-resources", "/swagger-resources");
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/swagger-ui.html**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/swagger-ui.html");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/api/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, yeah, this CORS thing is so badly implemented. I was stuck myself with React + Spring Boot + Spring Security.

What helped me is

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig{

   @Bean
   public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
       return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
           @Override
           public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/api/**")
                    .allowedOrigins("http://domain2.com")
                    .allowedMethods("*");
           }
       };
    }
}
```

I suggest you trying this method a little more. What I know for sure is that what you put in `allowedMethods` matters. I remember perfectly, that it didn't work for me when I listed all possible methods (including option). But it worked as soon as I changed this to `"*"`.

I also have separate `http.cors();` at the end of my `configure` method for Spring Security in case someone wonders about this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you just need addMapping and allowedOrigins, like:

```
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry myCorsRegistry){
    myCorsRegistry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
}
```

Thanks,